# org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException on I18N properties

Tags: java, spring, jsp, inversion-of-control

I was trying to understand the concept of internationalization (I18N) in spring framework by deploying a simple dynamic web project. I am getting an unsolvable problem. Following were the jar files used:

```
*commons-logging.jar
*org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.asm-sources-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.beans-sources-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.context-sources-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.core-sources-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
*org.springframework.expression-sources-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Following were the properties files:

**Data_ka.properties**

```
label=&#3257;&#3270;&#3256;&#3248;&#3265;
```

**Data_hi.properties**

```
label=&#2344;&#2366;&#2350;&#2381;
```

XML file:

**spring.xml**

```
<!-- spring - I18N deomo -->
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN 2.0//EN"
            "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans-2.0.dtd">
<beans>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="resources/Data" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

JSP file:

**index.jsp**

```
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Locale"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

 <% 
    String lang= request.getHeader("accept-language");
    Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
    ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
    String value = ap.getMessage("label",null,locale);  
 %>

 <form action="./hello">
    <%= value %> :<input type="text" name="name" />
                <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </form>
```

I am getting errors in my console as follows:

```java
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;C:\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\.dnx\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft DNX\Dnvm\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\apache-opennlp-1.7.2\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_BIN_PATH%;C:\Users\Nithin\Anaconda3;C:\Users\Nithin\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\Nithin\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\Nithin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\eclipse-jee-neon-2-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:50 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Spring1_IOC7_I18N' did not find a matching property.
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:53 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:54 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 5091 ms
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Dec 09, 2017 10:45:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:01 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [3,560] milliseconds.
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:03 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:03 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 9342 ms
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:19 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a35458e: startup date [Sat Dec 09 22:46:19 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/spring.xml]
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:20 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@61e5c0d: defining beans [messageSource]; root of factory hierarchy
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:20 PM org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource getResourceBundle
WARNING: ResourceBundle [resources/Data] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name resources/Data, locale en-us,en-in;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Dec 09, 2017 10:46:20 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Spring1_IOC7_I18N] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 11

8:      String lang= request.getHeader("accept-language");
9:      Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
10:     ApplicationContext ap = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources/spring.xml");
11:     String value = ap.getMessage("label",null,locale);  
12:  %>
13: 
14:  <form action="./hello">


Stacktrace:] with root cause
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'label' for locale 'en-us,en-in;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'.
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource.getMessage(AbstractMessageSource.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getMessage(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1161)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:75)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("lang");
```

should be

```
Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
```

without the quotes

Comment: Yea i have corrected the code ... still i am getting same error .

Comment: It can't be _exactly_ the same error, it should now show a different locale name, whatever you got from `request.getHeader("accept-language")`.  Make sure you have a resource for that locale.

Comment: The message was changed like this :org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'label' for locale 'en-us,en-in;q=0.7,en;q=0.3'.

Comment: You will have to parse the `accept-language` header to extract valid locales to use.

Comment: Can you suggest me the ways to parse the accept-language header ??